# What is the meaning of ([]Constructor)(nil)

Tags: go, slice

I was reading the source code of the Middleware's chaining software Alice and found the expression:

```
func New(constructors ...Constructor) Chain {
    return Chain{append(([]Constructor)(nil), constructors...)}
}
```

I have no problem with the code at all, except that i have never seen the expression `([]Slice)(nil)` before. Does anybody have any information about this sort of expression?

Answer (score 2):

It copies the `constructors` argument into a new slice, assigned it to a field in the `Chain` literal, and returns the new struct.

It is equivalent to

```
func New(constructors ...Constructor) Chain {
    var tmp []Constructor
    tmp = append(tmp, constructors...)
    return Chain{tmp}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The author of alice here, just randomly clicked on this question. :)

The other answers explain what the `append(nil, ...)` does - I use it throughout the library to copy the slices that the user passes in.

Now, Go does not allow to simply use `append(nil, someElement)` because the type of `nil` is unknown. `([]Constructor)(nil)` is casting `nil` to the type `[]Constructor` in order to avoid this. This is a type conversion, same as, say, `int64(123)` or `(*int)(nil)`.

This is a minimal example where the compiler errors out because of an untyped nil:

```
a := ([]int)(nil)
a = append(a, 1, 2, 3) // works fine, a is of type []int
var b []int
b = append(b, 1, 2, 3) // works fine, b is of type []int
c := nil
c = append(c, 1, 2, 3) // compiler error: the type of c is unknown
```

Comment: Oh yes, it's a simple cast! Somehow I didn't recognize it as such, i thought it was some strange expression i was not aware of. Thank you very much!